# Asynchronous cross-domain GET requests

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Does anyone has any solutions on accomplishing asynchronous cross-domain GET requests. I am looking to make a site that checks available names of other sites. **The faster the better.**

I'd like it to use my server if possible, as its most likely faster than the client. Would most likely send it a huge array (300-10000) requests.

Examples, links, anything will work.

Comment: Are you really going to be checking username availability on up to 10,000 external sites?  That is going to result in an enormous amount of traffic.

Comment: @Joey, no the user can check up to 10,000 from 1 site. 10,000 was a high in guess. There will be a database of "rejected" names if some are already tried. The site will allow copy and paste and then you just "check all names". I assuming people will copy and paste a long dictionary list..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make a same-domain get request to your server, and have your PHP script do the checking (maybe using CURL) before responding to the request.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to perform the Cross-Domain Check using JavaScript or using PHP?

If using JavaScript you will probably be restricted by the Same-Origin Policy, though some pages may allow your browser to access them using Ajax.

If using PHP there is no way to perform a asynchronous request, because PHP is synchronous all over.

Maybe a good variant would be to send a request to a Node.JS server from your JavaScript and then let Node.JS get the page without blocking a process?

Answer (score 0):

Check out curl http://us.php.net/curl